# Nginx cannot open the page

Tags: linux, nginx, server, debian

I just build a web server using nginx and i try to change the root path but it failed. It doesnt open the page instead download a file. Also the extension of the file was not specified. Sorry for my english. Anyone can help me to fix this? here it is my sites-available/default:

```
 # You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/rahma/wordpress;
#       root   /var/www/rahma;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /doc {
        root   /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location /images {
        root   /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
    }

    #error_page  404  /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/rahma/wordpress;
#       root   /var/www/rahma;

    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
        #proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #includefastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
        #deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#listen   8000;
#listen   somename:8080;
#server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#location / {
#root   html;
#index  index.html index.htm;
#}
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#listen   443;
#server_name  localhost;

#ssl  on;
#ssl_certificate  cert.pem;
#ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
#ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

#location / {
#root   html;
#index  index.html index.htm;
#}
#}
```

Before set the root to wordpress, i just add index.php on line 'index' and create a file php.info but it doens't work too.